# What does * of * matches mean in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

When you do a (regex) search in Sublime Text 2, it shows for example "230 of 973 matches". What does this mean? One would think that means that 230 of the 973 matches are selected, but this is not the case because only one match is selected by default.

[image: Sublime text matching count]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply means that the 230th match from the beginning of the file is being selected, from the total of 973 matches.

At the beginning of the file, you should be getting 1 of 973 matches, because the first match will be highlighted.

Comment: Verified this.. thanks! Strange that I didn't notice that myself. Will mark as accepted answer in a few minutes. If it would be 230th of 973 matches it would already be much clearer.